# Как получить название файла из свойств python?

Tags: python

Как я могу получить название файла из свойств при помощи Python?

[image: Скриншот Панели свойств]

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, вы можете использовать для этого pywin32:

```
import win32api
import win32con

def get_file_properties(file_path):
    # Получаем дескриптор файла
    handle = win32api.CreateFile(
        file_path,
        win32con.GENERIC_READ,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ,
        None,
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        None
    )
    
    # Получаем инфу файла
    info = win32api.GetFileInformationByHandle(handle)
    
    # Закрываем дескриптор
    win32api.CloseHandle(handle)
    
    return info

file_path = 'C:/путь_к_файлу/файл.txt'
value = get_file_properties(file_path)
print(value)
```

Comment: а что он выдает? Имя файла?

Comment: Получает всю информацию из окошка подробно, можете сами посмотреть вывод

Comment: не могу, у меня win32api говорит, что нет CreateFile